# Declaring a Perl array and assigning it values by an array-slice

Tags: perl, slice

I was trying to split a string and rearrange the results, all in a single statement:

```
my $date_str = '15/5/2015';
my @directly_assigned_date_array[2,1,0] = split ('/', $date_str);
```

This resulted in:

```
syntax error at Array_slice_test.pl line 16, near "@directly_assigned_date_array["
```

Why is that an error?

The following works well though:

```
my @date_array;
@date_array[2,1,0] = split ('/', $date_str);
```

@vol7ron offered a different way to do it:

```
my @rvalue_array = (split '/', $date_str)[2,1,0];
```

And it indeed does the job, but it looks unintuitive, to me at least.

Comment: You can't slice a declaration

Comment: I don't know why you've called it `@rvalue_array` as it certainly isn't an rvalue. Think of the statement as *declare `@rvalue_array` and set it to the third, second, and first fields of the date string*.

Comment: "it looks unintuitive" - well you'll need to adjust your intuition, your version seems very odd to me :-)

Comment: OK @Mat, will do! My "intuition" was that the list produced on the RHS is assigned to members 2, 1 and 0 on the LHS. Many times data arrives in the "wrong" order from an external source. My receiving array receives data from multiple external arrays. A given source contributes to non contiguous members of the receiving array. So for example, I use `@receiver[5,0,2] = @source[3,6,9]`. IMHO, this is a great feature. Don't you think so?

Comment: You can't declare an array slice. You have to declare the array first, then use it in a slice. `my @a;` declares an array. Then you can use it, as in `@a[2,1,0] = split m{/}, $date;`

Answer (score 3):

As you are just reversing the splitted array you can accomplish the same using this single statement: `@date_array = reverse(split('/',$date_str));`

Comment: Yes, reversing it would would be appropriate since our local convention is dd/mm/yyyy. If my input would be the American date format of mm/dd/yyyy the slice would have been `[2,0,1]` and reverse wouldn't cut it.

Answer (score 3):

Others here know much more about Perl internals than myself, but I assume it cannot perform the operation because an array slice is referencing an element of an array, which does not yet exist.  Because the array has not yet been declared, it wouldn't know what address to reference.

```
my @array = ( split '/', $date_str )[2,1,0];
```

This works because [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) returns values in list context.  Lists and arrays are very similar in Perl.  You could think of an array as a super list, with extra abilities.  However you choose to think of it, you can perform a list [slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) just like an array slice.

In the above code, you're taking the list, then reordering it using the slice and then assigning that to array.  It may feel different to think about at first, but it shouldn't be too hard.  Generally, you want your data operations (modifications and ordering) to be performed on the rhs of the assignment and your lhs to be the receiving end.

Keep in mind that I've also dropped some parentheses and used Perl's smart order of operation interpreting to reduce the syntax.  The same code might otherwise look like the following (same operations, just more fluff):

```
my @array = ( split( '/', $date_str ) )[2,1,0];
```

As [@luminos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4748333/luminos) mentioned, since you only have 3 elements you're manually reversing it, you could use a reverse function; again we can make use of Perl's magic order of operation and drop the parentheses here:

```
my @array = reverse split '/', $date_str;
```

But in this case it might be too magical, so depending on your coding practice guidelines, you may want to include a set of parentheses for the split or reverse, if it increases readability and comprehension.

Comment: I never rely on "magic". Saving key strokes and disk space is bad motivation. Also, anybody in the future who is less aware of the magic might not understand. (And I am not referring to just this example. I am talking about it as a general practice.)

Comment: @MeirG: You are using magic every time you write in any computer language

Comment: It's important to know the tools you use and the proper way to use them.  I call some of this *magic* because its operating in a way a little different from lower level languages like C.  However, the *magic* has been documented and is common practice.  Each programming language has its own variety of *magic*, but that's no reason not to use it.  Similar cases can be found in other scripting languages like Ruby or Swift.

Comment: @MeirG `Also, anybody in the future who is less aware of the magic might not understand.` This is always a tough subject for debate and it's important to know your audience and successor.  I have been burned because some other *programmer* didn't take the time to learn the language by reading the manual.  Those type of people are more hackers than programmers or professionals.  They are only hacking at the language.

Comment: I can see no magic here, it's completely clear and works as intended.

Comment: @VadimPushtaev the magic is that perl is able to interpret arguments correctly, without the need to disambiguate.  For instance, the code above could have been executed as `reverse(split('/'), $date_str)` which is obviously a logical error, but will still execute (`$_` would be used in the split).  Perl is smart; however, it can sometimes be too smart for our own good if we have many more functions/methods stacked in the expression/statement.  But you are correct, the above is working as intended